# java.lang.Long and scala.Long

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I don't know what happened in my code...

Logs are here.

```
[error] blahblah\SampleApp.scala:22:53: overloaded method value reduce with alternatives:
[error]   (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ReduceFunction[java.lang.Long])java.lang.Long <and>
[error]   (func: (java.lang.Long, java.lang.Long) => java.lang.Long)java.lang.Long
[error]  cannot be applied to ((java.lang.Long, java.lang.Long) => scala.Long)
[error]     val sumHundred = sparkSession.range(start, end).reduce(_ + _)
```

When I ran this code in **scala 2.11.12, spark 2.3.2** it works without any ERROR.
And same code in **scala 2.12.7, spark 2.4.0** it doesn't works - what?

Anybody knows about this?

```
  private val (start, end) = (1, 101)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sumHundred = sparkSession.range(start, end).reduce(_ + _)
    logger.debug(f"Sum 1 to 100 = $sumHundred")
    close()
  }
```

There's a parent `trait` that builds `sparkSession` etc.

What I've tried:

1. Explicit declaration of type:  
   `private val (start: Long, end: Long) = ...`
2. Similar things in `reduce` code.

What I know:
Perfectly compatiable between `scala.Long` and `java.lang.Long`

Comment: As a workaround, maybe you can try passing `(a,b) => Long.box(a + b)`  to reduce instead of `_ + _`

Comment: @giladhoch what the... Thank you SO much you saved my day. I don't even know that `Long.box` thing.

Comment: @giladhoch Why this happens? What's the difference between `_+_` and `box`?

Comment: `Long.box` wraps the primitive `Long` in the corresponding java Object. Spark API should seamlessly do the conversion for you, but since the error message appears like they don't, it wouldn't hurt to do it yourself. I guess this counts as a bug which you can open an issue for on the spark repo (if doesn't already exist)

Comment: @giladhoch Thanks again. Hope you have a wonderful day.

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help out :)

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with Spark version.
It is due to diffrences in Scala implementation between 2.11. and 2.12.
You can see how code actual look like for line

```
val sumHundred = sparkSession.range(start, end).reduce(_ + _)
```

in Scala 2.11 (with scala.this.Predef.long2Long conversion)

```
val sumHundred: Long = sparkSession.range(start.toLong, end.toLong).reduce(((x$2: Long, x$3: Long) => scala.this.Predef.long2Long(scala.this.Predef.Long2long(x$2).+(scala.this.Predef.Long2long(x$3)))));
```

and Scala 2.12 (implicit conversions are not applied)

```
val <sumHundred: error>: <error> = sparkSession.range(start.toLong, end.toLong).<reduce: error>(((x$2: Long, x$3: Long) => x$2.$plus(x$3)));
```

Your code will compile if you add a flag `scalacOptions += "-Xsource:2.11"`.

This page has more info [SAM conversion precedes implicits](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/)

PS. I would say the main source of amusement here is this SparkSession.range() method, which takes Scala Long parameters and returns Java Long value.

```
  def range(start: Long, end: Long): Dataset[java.lang.Long] = {
```

I would say it would be more consistent to choose one of them.

Comment: The scalacOptions must be input at ```build.sbt``` right? How should one go about this if they want implicit conversions in the REPL of spark-shell?

Comment: `spark-shell -DscalacOptions += "-Xsource:2.11"`  this should work for you.