# Spark forcing usage of java.lang.Long instead of scala.Long

Tags: scala, apache-spark

`x` is a `Dataset[Long]` with a single column, it was created using [`SparkSession.range`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#range(start:Long,end:Long,step:Long):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BLong%5D).
A single `reduce` operation on `x` using the anonymous `_+_` addition functions should return me a `Long` value.
But instead I get the following error:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.0
      /_/
         
Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.11)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> spark
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@a90447f

scala> val x = spark.range(0, 10000000, 10)
x: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> x.reduce(_+_)
<console>:26: error: overloaded method value reduce with alternatives:
  (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ReduceFunction[java.lang.Long])java.lang.Long <and>
  (func: (java.lang.Long, java.lang.Long) => java.lang.Long)java.lang.Long
 cannot be applied to ((java.lang.Long, java.lang.Long) => scala.Long)
       x.reduce(_+_)
```

Even after writing a function with well-defined types do we get this:

```
scala> def add(a:Long, b:Long):Long = a+b
add: (a: Long, b: Long)Long

scala> x reduce (add(_,_))
<console>:28: error: overloaded method value reduce with alternatives:
  (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ReduceFunction[java.lang.Long])java.lang.Long <and>
  (func: (java.lang.Long, java.lang.Long) => java.lang.Long)java.lang.Long
 cannot be applied to ((java.lang.Long, java.lang.Long) => scala.Long)
       x reduce (add(_,_))
```

But if I write a aggregating function explicitly using `java.lang.Long` for both the parameters, and the return type. Only then does it work.

```
scala> def add(a:java.lang.Long, b:java.lang.Long):java.lang.Long = a+b
add: (a: Long, b: Long)Long

scala> x.reduce(add(_,_))
res10: Long = 4999995000000
```

I don't think this is an issue everyone must be facing, do we really have to use `java.lang.Long` everywhere while using `Long` in Spark with Scala?
There has to be a better method, this is too long.

Comment: Does this answer you question-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425268/java-lang-long-and-scala-long

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't answer it, but points it in the right direction.

Comment: In that comment section one workaround has been suggested-->x.reduce((a,b) => Long.box(a + b)). Is it not working for you?

Comment: No, it isn't. ```x.reduce((a:Long,b:Long) => Long.box(a+b))``` gives the same error.

Comment: `x.reduce((a,b) => Long.box(a+b))` This should work for you.

Comment: Okay this works, but this is so weird. ```x reduce ((a,b) => Long.box(a+b))``` works. But ```x.reduce(Long.box(_+_))``` doesn't.  
I also cannot find ```box``` method in the [docs](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.10/scala/Long.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reduce()` function will take either scala.Long or java.lang.Long and return corresponding types.

`spark.range()` will return `java.lang.Long`, you can change that to `scala.Long` and call `reduce()` or convert reduce output to `java.lang.Long` using  `Long.box()`.

```
scala>  spark.range(0, 10000000, 10).reduce((a,b) => Long.box(a + b))
res4: Long = 4999995000000

scala> spark.range(0, 10000000, 10).as[Long].reduce(_+_)
res5: Long = 4999995000000
```

Comment: The latter one looks so much better, thank you. 
Are there no ways to bring autoboxing, incase of a ```build.sbt``` there seems to be. But what can one do in a ```spark-shell``` or in a notebook?

Comment: `spark-shell -DscalacOptions += "-Xsource:2.11"` this should work for you.